# elapsed time using System.currentTimeMillis not working on android

Tags: java, android

please i'm a having a problem with getting the elapsed time between performing some actions. The code is meant to perform an action after 1 mins(60,000 millisecs.) but when i run the code on my emulator, the elapsed time difference is usually smaller then expected and often close to the value in Thread.sleep(). i have tried using System.nanoTime() and even SystemClock.uptimeMillis()  ... i did a similar thing in normal java environment and it worked fine . could the problem be from the emulator and is there a way to do this?

```
     long startTime=0;
     long elapsedTime=0;
     long totalTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while (running) {

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            totalTime += elapsedTime;
            Log.d("elapsed","displaying time...."+elapsedTime);

            if(totalTime > 60000){
                Log.d("mins","one mins gone");
                totalTime = 0;
            }

              // do some other things here

         try {
            Thread.sleep(9000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        }

    }
```

Comment: where did you declare your endTime variable?

Comment: If all you want to do is perform an action once every minute then use a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registered to listen for `ACTION_TIME_TICK` - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Comment: @Abdi  thnx for noticing it . its supposed to be elapsedTime

Comment: @squonk thnk i'm checking on it now and i think it can help me but will it be able to work for a time like 69 secs if i need it cuz it seems be working per minuite

Answer (score 0):

System.currentTimeMillis() should work. However I am not sure if that is appropriate for your situation. Putting a thread into sleep is not the best way to preform time related tasks.

If you are using version 5.0, you can make use of the [JobScheduler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API.

For versions below 5.0, try using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for either one time or recurring alarms.

```
    AlarmManager alarm=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, _YOURBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 9000 , pi);
```

You need to implement a a broadcast reveiver which will be triggered when it is time.

Comment: wow thnx ... This is actually good i'll try it out and give a reply on how it goes

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are assigning the `startTime` in the `while` loop and that means that in the last iteration of the loop it's assigned to the time of that so It will be calculated as the thread sleeping time only as you mentioned.
You should assign it before the loop.